# How to get 5 meter accuracy in android GPS

Tags: android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

In my android application, i'm reading user's location and assigning it as their home location, but for some users when he/she checks again, it is showing the user is away from his home by more than 200 meters, in this case again the user has to reassign his location, i've learned that this might be because of the location accuracy of the device. I just wanted to make sure that the practice is follow for receiving GPS lat,lon is good or is there something i can improve,

following is the manifest permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

following is the code for storing location in a variable,

```
val fusedLocationClient = FusedLocationProviderClient(application)
private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
var curLoc = MutableLiveData<Array<Double>>()


val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()?.apply {
            interval = 5000
            fastestInterval = 2500
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest!!)

        val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(requireActivity())

        val task: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
        task.addOnSuccessListener { locationSettingsResponse ->
            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
            // location requests here.
            // ...

//            val locationCallback: LocationCallback
            locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                    locationResult ?: return

                    for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                        if (location.isFromMockProvider) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireActivity(), "Mock Location Enabled",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
//                                fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
                        } else {
                            val lat = location.latitude
                            val lon = location.longitude
                            val arr = arrayOf(lat, lon)
                            curLoc.value = arr
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper()
            )
        }
        val REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 111
        task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->

            if (exception is ResolvableApiException) {
                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                // by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    exception.startResolutionForResult(
                        requireActivity(),
                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
                    )
                } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
            }
        }
```

with the above code, i'm saving last location in variable curloc. when user tries to assign location as their home, i'm waiting for 10 sec(just giving time to get more accurate location) and then taking curLoc as their home lat and lon, so the location update received on the 10th second will be their home lat and lon.

Is this practice good or is there any good practice available for getting accurate location in 5 meters?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#getAccuracy()

Comment: If the accuracy is less then what can i do to increase the accuracy?Should i have to wait more time for getting the required accuracy? and is there any issue with the above approach?

Comment: Subscribe to first fix event https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssStatus.Callback#onFirstFix(int) that way you can just let user continue on their way and store the location when the device finally got an accurate position